# Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, then if $A \subseteq B$ then $A \cap B = A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets, then if $A \subseteq B$ then $A \cap B = A$.

How do I prove the above? I'm new to proving, please help!

What are the steps I need to create a proof? I'm really lost.

Now I know that the above is true (I can visualize it, and I can even draw a Venn diagram for it) but I don't really follow on formal proofs.

How should I know what to do? Do I use a let $x$ for $A$? or something else?

Comment: Formal proofs usually rely on the definitions of the terms involved.  Review your definitions of subset, intersection, and set equality.  Use these in your proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prove two sets are equivalent we need to prove that they contain eachother. By definition of the intersection we have $A\cap B\subseteq A$. Now for the opposite inclusion. Choose $x\in A$. Then, since $A\subseteq B$ we have $x\in B$ and thus $x\in A\cap B$, which implies that $A\subseteq A\cap B$. We conclude that $A = A\cap B$.

To get an intuitive feeling for sets I always draw circles on paper and look at the intersections and unions;)

Comment: I think I understood it. Do you have other general tips for me on how to prove? I can always seem to visualize it (like I get it intuitively) but I have trouble thinking, hey I need to let $x \in A$ to prove here and here...

Comment: My usual way to approach problems like this is first to draw the sets and see if it's intuitively true. The next step is to show both inclusions. This can generally done by choosing a random element in set 1 and showing that it is contained in set 2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what $A\subseteq B$ means: "if $x\in A$, then $x\in B$. Like Marc said in his answer, to show two sets are equivalent, you need to show that they contain each other; that is, in order to show that $A\cap B = A$, then you need to show that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A\cap B$. Let's do this.

**$(\subseteq):$** Given $A\subseteq B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\in B$ because $A\subseteq B$; that is, $x\in A\cap B$. Thus, $A\subseteq A\cap B$.

**$(\supseteq):$** Given $A\subseteq B$. If $x\in A\cap B$, then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Hence, surely $x\in A$. Thus, $A\cap B\subseteq A$.

Thus, given $A\subseteq B$, you have shown that $A\cap B\subseteq A$ and $A\subseteq A\cap B$, ultimately showing that $A\cap B = A$, which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: I think you've reversed $\subseteq$ and $\supseteq$.

Comment: @AriBrodsky What I meant to communicate was that, in the first, we showed $A\subseteq A\cap B$ and, in the second part, $A\supseteq A\cap B$ (using the perspective of $A$ coming first and moving left to right). Could probably be clearer though.